# Is there some fixed overhead running time to sklearn transform?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was hoping to use the PCA module in sklearn to do some real-time transformation on user features in our app (for a spam detection algorithm). The lead of our team has specified that the model would need to make a prediction under 100 ms (preferably 10-50 ms). So far in my timing tests, I'm getting about 150 ms. This is with very small amount of data (i.e. the minimum amount I could conceivably use in a real application). Just wondering if anyone has come upon this issue and if so, what can I do about it? At some point, would I need to take the plunge and roll my own PCA? My first thought was that if sklearn can't do it that quickly, I can't imagine my naive code would be able to do it any faster. Is Python just to limited performance-wise for a real-time application like this?

To build the model, there is a set of transformers combined in a feature union:

```
    transformer_list=[
        ('age', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ColumnSelector(column='birthdate')),
            ('birthdate', BirthdateTransformer()),
            ('vect', DictVectorizer(sparse=False))
        ])),
        ('domain', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ColumnSelector(column='email')),
            ('counter', EmailDomainName()),
            ('vect', DictVectorizer(sparse=False))])),
        ('sex', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ColumnSelector(column='sex')),
            ('dict', DictTransformer()),
            ('vect', DictVectorizer(sparse=False))
        ]))],
    n_jobs=2,
    transformer_weights=weights)
```

The only custom classes there are BirthdateTransformer and EmailDomainName:

```
class BirthdateTransformer(TransformerMixin):
    """
    takes list of Unix timestamps (seconds since epoch) and converts to list of ages in years
    """

    def fit(self, dates, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, timestamps, y=None):
        return [{'age group': age_group(ts / 1000)} for ts in timestamps]

class EmailDomainName(TransformerMixin):
    """
    Class for building sklearn Pipeline step. This class takes a list of email addresses and returns a list of dicts
    created by the Counter class from the collections module.
    """

    regex = re.compile(r"@[\w.]+")

    def pre_filter(self, email_list):

        for e in email_list:
            match = self.regex.search(e)

            if match is not None:
                yield match.group()
            else:
                yield ""

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, email_list):
        """
        Use regular expression to pull out domain name from email address and convert to list of dicts containing
        count of characters.
        :param email_list:
        :return:
        """

        return [{k: v for (k, v) in Counter(result).most_common()} for result in
                self.pre_filter(email_list)]
```

Then I simply pass in a Pandas dataframe with the data and call transform() on the data to be projected into PCA space.

Comment: Could you list the exact steps involved in the 150ms? If you had some sample code that would make it clearer. I'm a bit confused by the "very small amount of data", aren't you timing prediction for a single sample?

Comment: I should have said a small amount of features.

Comment: Could you add some code so we can pinpoint what's wrong (or see everything's right)? I think "A small amount of features" does not really make sense in the context of an already-fit PCA. Unless you mean you fit the PCA with a small amount of features?... Code would make it clearer ;)

Comment: I added the code that defines the model. As you can see, there's really not that much going on here. Have you built models that run faster (say < 50 ms)? If I knew that it was possible, I'd keep digging. If it's not possible, then I need to know that.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. I don't know if that can run under 50ms, but I'd be surprised if it was not possible. Are you sure that it is the PCA that is taking the bulk of the 150ms? Transforming is just a dot product between the feature vector and the principal components. With 50 components and 2000 features I get 224us for `PCA.transform` on my laptop.

Comment: Are you using `PCA` or `RandomizedPCA`? That is part of why we want more code. We need to see the exact call (and everything involved) that you want to run in 100 ms. Can't help otherwise.

Comment: @Andreus I'm using PCA with 2 components. The code that I want to run < 100 ms is simply a call to transform(). I have shown the code that is needed to transform the data. What else do you need to see exactly?

Comment: @user3914041what kind of features are you using? Do you do any transformations of the data first or are you simply using numerical features? Maybe the issue is using Pandas here instead of numpy array or something? Also, I'm using the Pipeline to combine different types of features. Maybe that is slow.

Comment: @user3914041what timing function are you using?

Comment: @EvanZamir I used `%timeit` from IPython. I'm using numerical features I got with `from sklearn.datasets import make_classification`, using 2000 features as I mentioned. You can try to reproduce it on your computer. Once the PCA is fit, calling transform with 2 components is just a matter of computing 2 dot products. This is very unlikely the bottleneck in your case. We'd need more detail about how this is running, if you want to go wild and give us a reproducible example with actual data we could look into it. I think the overhead is more in the transform part.